# After upgrading I keep getting 'This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK'

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have two apps in the app store, both through MonoTouch but after upgrading to all new versions just before trying to upload a third app (a modified version of the second app) I keep getting this message in Application Loader:

**'This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK'.**

I have changed the project options in Monotouch Build - iPhone build - general - to use 'use SDK version' from 4.0 to 3.0 but to no avail.  This all used to work but now after upgrading the recommended upgrades it isn't working anymore...

After some digging these are my current settings:  MonoDevelop: 2.4.2  MonoTouch 4.0  MonoFramework 2.10.7  and checking in the Software\Developer settings my iPhone OS: 3.2 and 4.0  and iPhone Simulator: 3.2 and 4.0

Is there an easy way to undo something I did? Also, what exactly does Apple mean with WHAT version of WHICH SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that you have the latest update of MonoDevelop. You can find the MonoDevelop release ID in the *MonoDevelop->About MonoDevelop* menu, then the *Build Info* tab. It should be 20402004 if you're using the stable version of MonoDevelop, or 20509002 if you're using the beta.

You also should have the latest build of Apple's iPhone SDK, which is installed along with Xcode. If you have multiple versions of Xcode installed (we recommend keeping Xcode 3.2.6 installed *somewhere* if you use Interface Builder, so you can set IB as the deafult handler for xib files), the important one is the one in /Developer/Applications. If you're using Xcode 3.2.6, I'm not sure how you can easily check the SDK version, but you should have the new build that was released on March 26th. If you're using Xcode 4, its version in the About box should be 4.0.1.

Comment: Hi mhutch - thanks for your response - my MonoDevelop release ID is indeed 20402004.

Comment: Hi mhutch - thanks for your response - my MonoDevelop release ID is indeed 20402004. Sorry, hit the enter key - I have just installed ALL the new versions I was prompted to: i.e. MonoTouch, MonoDevelop and MonoFramework (version numbers in my initial question).  My Developer Information: tells me I have Xcode 3.2.3 installed.  Is this good or bad?  It has been working fine before - and I have never installed any updates (as far as I can remember) of Xcode. I only see Xcode when I get new provisioning profiles, then it is back to MonoDevelop/Touch again.   Am I missing something??

Comment: MonoTouch uses the Apple iOS SDK for various parts of the compilation process, so you need to keep the Apple SDK up to date.